# How to iterate an object in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sanitize

One of my angularjs function has an object.

```
var obj = this.getPersonObject();
```

I'm not sure what all properties would be present in that object, as this function is in a third party lib.

My need is I will have to iterate through all properties of that object and escape html characters if any.

At the top of my head, I think of this:

```
for(var key in obj){
      var escapedHtml = escapeHTMLChars(obj[key]);
      obj[Key] = escapedHtml;
   }
```

Are there any other better ways to do this ?

I also have `lodash`, will any pre-built function within lodash, which will be of any help?

Comment: Better how? What's wrong with your `for-in` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is fine, however, you can also use the `forEach` function of AngularJs. [Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

```
var output = {};
angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
   output[key] = escapeHTMLChars(value);
});
```

Comment: I want a different method as this is not a right way to operate. that is, not modifying object's value within a loop.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: It's perfectly fine to modify the value of properties in a `forEach` (or `for-in`) loop.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for clarifying that... In C# or .NET, I was not advised to modify or remove the values from a foreach loop during iteration. So, I assume it is language specific ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: Modifying is different from removing. It's very awkward to modify an entry in a C# `foreach` loop (though it's possible), normally if you need to, you'd use `for` instead.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Ok, so If I understand correctly: Modifying an entry in an array is possible while on iteration with respect to any programming language, it is not a bad practice. right ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: It depends on the iteration mechanism being used, but no, it's not universally bad practice.

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder. Learned something new.